# transformation of vector fields under coordinate transformations

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus

Consider two open subsets $\Omega, \Omega^{\prime}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Now consider a (volume preserving) diffeomorphism
\begin{align}
 \varphi:\Omega^{\prime}\to\Omega; \alpha\to \varphi(\alpha)
\end{align}
If we have a (scalar) function $u\in C^1(\Omega)$, it will be transformed via $\tilde{u}=u\circ \varphi$. By differentiation, one can prove that the gradient of $u$ will be transformed according to
\begin{align}
 (\nabla u)\circ \varphi=(\nabla \tilde{u})(D\varphi)^{-1}
\end{align}
where $D\varphi$ denotes the Jacobian matrix of $\varphi$ and $\nabla \tilde{u}$ is taken to be a row vector.

Now consider an arbitrary vector field $v$ in $\Omega$ (i.e. an electric field or a velocity field, etc.), which is not necessarily a gradient field of some function, how does this transform under $\varphi$? Does it transform the same way? And if so, how can I prove it (or where can I look it up)?

Comment: On wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential). In general, a good place to start would be any of the older textbooks on tensor calculus.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out where to start. Since I have absolutely no background in differential geometry yet, your advise helped me search for what I need. I'm having some problems with the notation, but I think I've got it.

Answer (score 1):

Gradients are not vector fields; they are differential $1$-forms. Only in Riemannian geometry they have the option of becoming vector fields. The operation you described in the post is the [pullback of a differential form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_%28differential_geometry%29#Pullback_of_differential_forms).

For vector fields we have the [pushforward operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_%28differential%29#Pushforward_of_vector_fields). A vector field is a smooth selection of a tangent vector from every tangent space $T_pM$ (tangent at point $p$ of manifold $M$). The derivative of a smooth map $f:M\to N$ is a linear map from $T_pM$ to $T_{f(p)}N$. This linear map pushes the vector field from $M$ to $N$, in the *forward* direction. Compare this to the pullback, which moves differential forms from $N$ to $M$.